# iPhone: Progress Indicator

Tags: iphone

In my app when I download something from service, I show progress indicator:

```
 - (void)setupProgressIndicator {
    MBProgressHUD *progressHUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
    [self.view addSubview:progressHUD];
    self.progressIndicator = progressHUD;
    [progressHUD release];
 }

[self.progressIndicator show:YES];
```

My view has Navigation Bar which I setup in my AppDelegate, and when indicator is shown, I still can tup on Navigation Bar Buttons...Can MBProgressHUB cover whole screen ??? Because I don't want to disable buttons on sync start and than make them enable on sync finish...I think indicator should cover whole screen. Any ideas ? Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my implementation use it if you want
Put it in appDelegate and use from anywhere in the application.

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Waiting View
- (void)showWaitingView {

    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(90, 190, 32, 32);
    UIActivityIndicatorView* progressInd = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [progressInd startAnimating];
    progressInd.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge;

    frame = CGRectMake(130, 193, 140, 30);
    UILabel *waitingLable = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    waitingLable.text = @"Processing...";
    waitingLable.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    waitingLable.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];;
    waitingLable.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    UIView *theView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    theView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    theView.alpha = 0.7;
    theView.tag = 999;
    [theView addSubview:progressInd];
    [theView addSubview:waitingLable];

    [progressInd release];
    [waitingLable release];

    [window addSubview:[theView autorelease]];
    [window bringSubviewToFront:theView];
    [pool drain];
}

- (void)removeWaitingView {
    UIView *v = [window viewWithTag:999];
    if(v) [v removeFromSuperview];

}
```

Comment: That is fine, but how to rotate that ?

Comment: for rotation you need to use a UIViewController instead of UIView. Create a view Controller like loadingViewController and apply Rotation Code on that view controller you can use interface builder. It's a little bit cumbersome(tough) to achieve.

Comment: I bring to front my HUB  [window addSubview:[myHUB autorelease]];
    [window bringSubviewToFront:myHUB]; and that works for me....Thanks....

Answer (score 1):

usual thing is to add an transparent view cover the entire screen and that will capture touch event. or you can make your HUD the size of the screen, with visible widget only in the center.

Comment: man, you'll never progress if you don't search by yourself. there's already plenty of ressources about UIViews for you to find one good answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    - (IBAction)showWithCustomView:(id)sender {

        HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];

        [self.view addSubview:HUD];

        HUD.customView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"37x-Checkmark.png"]] autorelease];


        HUD.customView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);//Ur answer

        HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeCustomView;

        HUD.delegate = self;
        HUD.labelText = @"Completed";

        [HUD show:YES];
        [HUD hide:YES afterDelay:3];
    }
```

Comment: still it's not covered Navigation Bar...Navigation bar is like not a part of my view

Comment: [self wantsFullScreenLayout];

Comment: hey in urviewcontroller.m while u click the button to show the progress fist line should be this.this is viewcontroller method

Comment: [progressHUD release]; 
[self wantsFullScreenLayout];

Comment: Picture cover whole view, but navigation bar still available... (((

Comment: [self.navigationController wantsFullScreenLayout];